# Bootstrap 4 - CSS without any global styles

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm developing a small control which is directly embedded in a parent page (without iFrame).
My control is written using react-bootstrap, so the bootstrap4 css is also embedded along with my control.

While developing my app as standalone, everything was fine.
After embedding it however, it turns out that there are some "global" bootstrap styles, such as the so called "list-styles" that don't get applied only on HTML elements having bootstrap classes, but instead on any matching HTML tag.

This causes the parent page's layout to get scrambled once my control is loaded.
Examples for bootstrap classes that are applied globally and which cause problems for me are styles like these which can be found in the bootstrap4 default css:

```
dl, ol, ul {
       margin-top: 0;
       margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

or

```
label {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: .5rem;
}
```

This is very unfortunate for my use case. Is there a way for getting rid of any styles in bootstrap, which are not linked to any proper css bootstrap class? I don't want any styling of HTML tags that are not explicitly linked to a bootstrap class.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of three options, though I'm not sure they will do for you:

- Paste Bootstrap's styles into a local file (instead of getting them from a CDN or something) and delete what you don't want (most of the unwanted styles should be at the top of the file)
- Look for another, more minimal version of Bootstrap. I don't know if such versions/customizations exist but they very well might
- Don't use Bootstrap. You can just as easily write your own css lines (personally I find that Bootstrap makes you lose control over your styling, but that's my opinion)